# Attempt to de-reference a null object: Error though have data

Tags: controller, class, map, schema, describefieldresult

I am getting the subject error for below piece of code , exactly at below line. Though I have data in call object.Can someone please let me know the root cause and guide towards it's remedy?

error line:

> Schema.DescribeFieldResult  dfr =
>   callFieldMap.get(fldname).getDescribe() ;

```
// Get Field Maps
        acctFieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap();
        callFieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Call2_vod__c.fields.getMap();
        userFieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.User.fields.getMap();


        // Get values of custom settings
        css = [select Search_Field_Set__c,Extra_Condtion__c from Call_Search_Settings__c where name = 'Main'] ;
        searchFieldSet = css.Search_Field_Set__c.split(',') ;
        // Set up search fields
        searchFields = new List <searchField> () ;
        for (String f : searchFieldSet) {
            // String has the format <fieldname>:<options>, where fieldname is the API name of the field,
            // and options, is present, contains a combination of the letters s for starts with, e for exact match,
            // and c for contains.  If any of these are upper case, that is the default option value
            String fldname = (f.split(':'))[0] ;
            String opts = (f.split(':'))[1] ;
            if (fldname == 'CurrTerr') {
                searchFields.add (new searchField('Current Territory','CurrTerr')) ;
            }
            else if (fldname.startsWith('ACCT.')) {
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult  dfr = acctFieldMap.get(fldname.replace('ACCT.', '')).getDescribe() ;
                searchFields.add (new searchField('Account',dfr,opts)) ;
            }
            else if (fldname.startsWith('USER.')) {
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult  dfr = userFieldMap.get(fldname.replace('USER.', '')).getDescribe() ;
                searchFields.add (new searchField('User',dfr,opts)) ;
            }
            else {
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult  dfr = callFieldMap.get(fldname).getDescribe() ;
                searchFields.add (new searchField('Call2_vod__c',dfr,opts)) ;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the map is returning null for a field name. So I suggest you change your code to this:

```
if (callFieldMap.contains(fldname)) {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult  dfr = callFieldMap.get(fldname).getDescribe() ;
    searchFields.add (new searchField('Call2_vod__c',dfr,opts));
} else {
    throw new MyException('Invalid field name ' + fldname);
}
```

to identify the problem value if it is the result of a coding error somewhere else. If it is a user input then you will need to decide how to report the problem back to the user.

(See [Creating Custom Exceptions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex7_5.htm) for how to create an exception you can throw yourself.)

Comment: Yes Keith I was able to debug that. introduced a try catch and editted data to support the desired result and it works fine now.

Comment: @SFDC_GEEK Cool that you figured it out yourself.